# Mystery sum with placeholder digits

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, mathematics, integer

I came across this coding problem.

> Back in primary school, maybe you were sometimes asked to solve a
>   fill-in-the-blank sum - or "mystery sum" - in which certain digits are
>   removed and you had to figure out what they originally were.
>
> Now, it's time for serious business: sums with no digits, where every
>   digit is replaced by a letter. Within each seperate sum, a letter
>   replaces one digit and it is always the same letter for that one
>   digit.
>
> For example, in the sum below: A+BB=ACC The aim is to figure out which
>   digits are hidden behind the letters A, B and C so that the sum turns
>   out correct. Here, the solution is that A replaces 1, B replaces 9 and
>   C replaces 0; resulting in: 1+99=100
>
> Finally, there is the constraint that the length of the given word is
>   equal to the length of the hidden number. Thus, in the sum
>   CHEVAL+VACHE=OISEAU, CHEVAL is indeed a 6 digit number: the C (more
>   precisely the first letter of any word) cannot correspond to a zero.
>
> For each given sum, there is only one possible solution to the
>   problem. You are asked to write the result value of the sum to the
>   standard output.
>
> **INPUT:** One line : a sum in the form WORD1+WORD2=RESULT, in which each
>   word is a sequence of capital letters.
>
> **OUTPUT:** The result of the solved sum.
>
> **CONSTRAINTS:** Each sum has 2 to 20 words, each made up of 1 to 20
>   capital letters

I solved it using brute force checking against each permutation of assigned integers to the unique characters. Can anybody suggest a better strategy or algorithm?

```
public static void mysterySum(String equation) {
String[] breakUp = equation.split("=");
String[] lhs = breakUp[0].split("\\+");
String rhs = breakUp[1];

HashSet<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();
for (char charVal : equation.toCharArray()) {
    if (!(charVal == '+' || charVal == '=')) {
        charSet.add(new Character(charVal));
    }
}

char[] refCharVals = new char[10];

int i = 0;
for (Character charVal : charSet) {
    refCharVals[i++] = charVal;
}
while (i < 10)
    refCharVals[i++] = '=';

String refString = new String(refCharVals);
StringBuilder currRef = new StringBuilder();
checkAllPermutations(refString, currRef, lhs, rhs);

}

private static void checkAllPermutations(String string, StringBuilder outstr,   String[] lhs, String rhs) {

if (resultMatched)
    return;

HashSet<Character> current = new HashSet<>();
if (string.length() == 0) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> refChars = getRefMap(outstr);

    int sumLhs = 0;
    for (String strNumber : lhs) {
        int number = getnumber(strNumber, refChars);
        sumLhs += number;
    }

    int rhsNumber = getnumber(rhs, refChars);
    if(rhsNumber == sumLhs) {
        resultMatched = true;
    System.out.println(rhsNumber);}
    return;
}

char[] chars = string.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (current.add(chars[i])) {
        outstr.append(chars[i]);
        checkAllPermutations(string.substring(0, i) + string.substring(i + 1, string.length()), outstr, lhs, rhs);
        outstr.setLength(outstr.length() - 1);
        if(resultMatched) break;
    }

}

}

private static int getnumber(String strNumber,  HashMap<Character, Integer> refChars) {
int number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strNumber.length(); i++) {
    number = number * 10 + refChars.get(strNumber.charAt(i));
}
return number;

}

private static HashMap<Character, Integer> getRefMap(StringBuilder outstr) {
HashMap<Character, Integer> refChars = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < outstr.length(); i++) {
    if (outstr.charAt(i) != '=')
        refChars.put(outstr.charAt(i), i);
}

return refChars;
}
```

Comment: Is this how your code is really indented? (Use Ctrl-K to indent a whole code block.)

Answer (score 2):

As for a review of the code I would suggest to avoid acronyms (also recommend, as @200_success did, to better indent the code, in case this is how your code is indented).

As for the solution, I would strongly avoid brute force ones. This is a [cryptarithmetic problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_arithmetic) and, if you work only on base 10, you have 10! possible assignments, but if you generalize (for any base) then the problem is NP-complete. I would suggest to look for solutions for cryptarithmetic problems (usually they are described on texts/sources on AI).

Answer (score 1):

I think a good idea can be start by some "bounds steps" where you try to obtain bounds on your digits. For example, in `A + BB = ACC` you have `A >= 1` and `A <= 9`, `BB >= 11` and `BB <= 99`. From that, you can obtain that `ACC <= 108` and then `A=1`. Then, you inject `A=1` in the equation, and you restart this process.

If I should implement it, I think I start by a renaming of the variables in A,B,...,J. Then I work with :

- list of possible digits for each letter
- list of possible letters for each digit
- bounds on each word

and I update that at each new observation, and restart the step with the new constraints.

Comment: What happened to 10? You said BB>=11, and A<=9.

Comment: `BB` has 2 identical digits... the lowest is 11.

Comment: Only in that particular instance though.  May be good Rio note that

Comment: It's an example... Moreover, if you consider `AB` numbers, you have `AB >= 10` but `AB <= 98`. The bound depends of the word, of course.